# C++: Safest way to cast boost::optional<type> to type

Tags: c++, boost

C++ boost::optional question.
How can I cast boost::optional myInt to an int (safely). In my program I have an if statement that checks myInt is indeed initialized, so I want to pass it around in different functions as an int rather then boost::optional for readability purposes.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you could show some code to make your question more clear.

Comment: ... and read the documentation before playing with the toys...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you just do

```
boost::optional<int> x;
//....
//....
if (x)
{
    int y = *x;  // or y = x.get();
}
```